# VB6 Browse file and Connection

Tags: vb6

I want to browse file and upload as a new connection

```
     Private Sub BrowseBtn_Click()  

     CommonDialog1.ShowOpen
     Text1.Text = CommonDialog1.FileName

      End Sub

      Private Sub ConnectionBtn_Click()
      If con.State = 1 Then
      con.Close
      End If
      Set con = New ADODB.Connection
      con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =" & CommonDialog1

      End Sub
```

Error 394 Property Write Only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CommonDialog1 is a COM component. Use its property.

```
  con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =" & CommonDialog1.FileName
```

Or

```
  con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =" & Text1.Text
```

Since you already get its value